# How to pull subrepo tag instead of branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-tag, git-subrepo

I have a repository 'util' repository that I cloned as a subrepo into 'client' repo. How can I pull a tag version instead of a branch, in the client repo?

I dont want to be pulling version branches, so I dont have a lot of unused branches in the subrepo.

Comment: It's not a problem that a repository has a lot of unused branches. I think you mean `fetch` a tag instead of `pull` a tag. They are different. If you want to fetch a specific tag, use `git fetch origin +refs/tags/<tagname>:refs/tags/<tagsname>`. To fetch all tags, run `git fetch origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`.  In most repositories, fetching tags instead of branches does not reduce the repository size significantly.

Comment: Why? What problem does not pulling branches solve?

Comment: In the util repo, we are releasing versions with tags. I didn't want to keep creating a release branch for every release, to be pulled in the client repos... Instead I'd prefer to fetch the tag to be used in the client. The problem is that in gitsubrepo module, I didnt find a way to use tags in client repos...